# Regex to match code with fixed country code and variable wildcard usage

Tags: regex, expression, wildcard, maxlength, requirements

I need to implement a regex which cover several requirements. These are the following:

- A length restriction to **max 8 chars** should be done (with or
  without wildcard). In any case the code is never longer than 8 chars.
- When wildcard is given also lower then 8 digits is allowed. Without
  wildcard exactly 8 digits are needed.
- allowed characters are: **0-9A-Za-z*** (all digits, all chars, asterix as wildcard)
- pure wildcard must be possible
- else the first two digits **must contain a 2 chars** country code
  (alpha-numeric) and then **only** number or wildcards are allowed.
- after country code wildcard can be used at any place (in the middle, at the end, mutliple asterix/wildcards after each other also allowed)

I tried many things so far and thought about Lookahead/Lookbehind because of the asterix and the max. length.
My latest state which covers the most of the requirements is the following:

```
^([A-Za-z]{2}[0-9*]{0,6}|\*)$
```

check the [live demo with right/wrong combo](https://regex101.com/r/L6HaDG/1)

But in this example a code without asterix/wildcard is possible with less than 8 chars -> that's wrong.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance :)

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\*\*$)(?!.{9})(?:[A-Za-z]{2}(?:\d*(?:\*\d*)+|\d{6})|\*)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/L6HaDG/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seems to work :)
Could you please make a breakdown explanation especially for the beginning?
The rest is clear so far, but the beginning I don't understand :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!.*\*\*$)(?!.{9})(?:[A-Za-z]{2}(?:\d*(?:\*\d*)+|\d{6})|\*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6HaDG/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\*\*$)` - no two `**` at the end of string allowed
- `(?!.{9})` - the string must contain less than 9 chars other than line break chars
- `(?:[A-Za-z]{2}(?:\d*(?:\*\d*)+|\d{6})|\*)` - one of the two alternatives:

  - `[A-Za-z]{2}(?:\d*(?:\*\d*)+|\d{6})` - two letters and then  either  six digits or zero or more digits followed with one or more sequences of an asterisk and zero or more digits
  - `|`  - or
  - `\*` - an asterisk
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: thanks a lot for the breakdown! The first Lookahead confused me because I thought it looks for the asterix at the beginning, but it looks for 2 asterix at the end. Now I understand everything :)